# apache rewrite to assign folders to domains

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

Please point me in the right direction.

I am using .htaccess to set-up domains on my server.

I need to domain.com to access files from /domain.com/* folder.
If a file does not exist, load /domain.com/index.php
and domain.com/images/image.jpg should load file: /domain.com/images/image.jpg

One thing is that it should load everything without sending 302 "file moved" notices to browser.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't use .htaccess files for this. I don't even think you can - if I remember correctly, the necessary directives aren't allowed in .htaccess files.

Comment: This isn't a job for rewrite rules. It's a job for virtual hosts. (In fact, rewrite rules shouldn't be the first thing you think of when configuring Apache, anyway.)

Comment: I need to configure Zend framework to work with my other scripts. I would like to apply their example for multiple domains:
http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Configuring+Your+URL+Rewriter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a lot of domains, or even if you have only a few domains but they all have more or less the same configuration, this is the kind of situation that [dynamic mass virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html) is made for. Something like this would go in your `httpd.conf` file (or in a file that's included in `httpd.conf`):

```
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0/htdocs
ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error_log
CustomLog /var/www/logs/access_log combined
```

I'd also suggest

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

to load the `index.php` file in a directory if the client doesn't specify a filename.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a virtual host for every single domain you'd like to map to a file path, and specify the DocumentRoot of each vhost to the actual path on the filesystem. Then, you'll want to be sure you have a DEFAULT vhost, so that all other requests for domains that are not setup, will use the DEFAULT vhost. Lastly, you'll want to create a custom 404 error handler, so that if the file does not exist that is being requested, it will serve up alternative content. You will need to create a php called custom_404.php that displays a generic message and your /images/image.png.

```
# Default Domain (Undefined domains will fall back to this)
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias www.defaultdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/default/htdocs
    ErrorDocument 404 /custom_404.php
    ErrorLog /var/www/default/logs/error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/default/logs/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>

# domain1.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1.com/htdocs
    ErrorDocument 404 /custom_404.php
    ErrorLog /var/www/domain1.com/logs/error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/domain1.com/logs/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>

# domain2.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/htdocs
    ErrorDocument 404 /custom_404.php
    ErrorLog /var/www/domain2.com/logs/error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/domain2.com/logs/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this helps!

*-Kevin*

Answer (score 1):

You need to use virtual hosts to organize this.  Here is a sample virtual host file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.net
    ServerAlias www.example.net
    ServerAdmin traustitj@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/www.example.net/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/www.example.net/logs/errors.log
    Customlog /var/www/vhosts/www.example.net/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Place this file inside /etc/httpd/conf.d/
And call it for example, vhost_example.net.conf

And then add inside /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf in for example the last line

Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost_example.net.conf

(or just 
Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf
)
And in httpd.conf file, remember to make this line uncommented

NameVirtualHost *:80

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to know how it's done using rewriting in .htaccess. Also, that rewrite rule has to load index.php in case of a 404